# How to sort or order the date in sequence for reminder for Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I create reminders and I need to sort or arrange the order in ascending or descending order.

```
reminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions<Reminder>().Where(a => a.BeginTime.Month == intMth);
```

Example:

11/1/2011

11/8/2011

11/10/2011

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) or [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx) in your linq statement

*For example:*

```
   var l = new [] { 1, 2, 4}.OrderByDescending(a => a);

   foreach(var r in l)
    Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Will return 4,2,1

Comment: Thanks. I need to change it to OrderByDescending(a => a.Somedate);